# ASP.NET MVC Add View Dialog closing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

Recently a large project I work on started having a problem with the Add View dialog.  When clicking the `Add Strongly-typed View` checkbox, the spinner comes up the first time for about a second or two, and then the entire dialog just closes and disappears.  If I open the dialog and click the button again, it just closes again quickly.

The project is using ASP.NET MVC 2, I have installed VS2010 SP1 and this problem occurs with or without the MVC3 tools update installed.  It only happens with this project, and I have replicated the problem on 2 different development machines.  If I create a new MVC2 or MVC3 project, this does not happen at all, nor do any other small to medium sized projects I have.

I can of create a regular view and change it to strongly typed by myself, so there is a workaround, but this is still pretty annoying.  Any ideas what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: This just started happening to me too. Bummed nobody responded.

Comment: @JamesAlexander: If you try to add a controller, do you get an error related to a referenced library?  That's the only other odd issue we're running into regularly and they both started around the same time.

Comment: @NickLarsen I am having the exact problem you are describing. It is described here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080554/add-controller-after-recent-tools-update-fails-with-dependency-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080554/add-controller-after-recent-tools-update-fails-with-dependency-error). Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use version control? Make sure all the assemblies that your project depends on (i.e. referenced by the project itself or by its referenced assemblies) are in sync. I've just run into this (both "Add View" and "Add Controller" problems) after updating a bunch of projects from SVN and rebuilding some. The issue was fixed after I rebuilt several libraries that my MVC project depends on.

Comment: I had just given up on it and was creating them all manually.  When I saw your post I tried it again and today it is working.

Comment: I had this issue and solved it by simply cleaning the sln - this answer made me think of it though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I could not open the Add->Controller dialog either as described here: [Add Controller after recent tools update fails with dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080554/add-controller-after-recent-tools-update-fails-with-dependency-error/9142924#9142924). In my case, I had added models to my domain, but I had forgotten to add contexts for these new models; things like

```
public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
```

I had no error at compile time, and I was not using these models yes in the solution, so there was no error at run time either. I guess the problem can be anywhere though.