# Visual Studio 2010 - "Add View" Wizard Crashes on Strongly Typed Checkbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010

OK, This is strange and I am wondering if anyone out there has experienced it.

**Reproduction Steps:**

1. Right-click in Views folder in Solution Explorer
2. Name the view, select Razor as engine
3. Click the "Create a strongly-typed view checkbox
4. Get the spinning blue doughnut and the dialog closes

Has this happened to you? How do you resolve it? I guess I can create these views manually but
I'd really like to know what's going on.

I have saved, cleaned, rebuilt and also quit and relaunched VS too.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841902/asp-net-mvc-add-view-dialog-closing)

Comment: This happens to me as well, clean/rebuild as in @Luca's link does not work, have you had any luck with this?